# Error on delete from elasticsearch using curl command

Tags: elasticsearch

when I try to delete documents from my elasticsearch index it throws the following error:

{"ok":false,"message":"Deleted cluster."}

I had previously deleted this index and then created it again.
I can send documents to it and they reflect on kibana too. But i just cannot delete documents or do a search query through curl.

What does

Comment: You probably need to show the curl command you're running

Comment: curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/charts/logs/_doc/L04dU2gBnyB5Q6tBoTIw"   This is the curl command.

Comment: nor does this one work:                                                                                   
                                                                                                                        curl -X GET "localhost:9200/charts/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "price"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many types in your query, either `logs` or `_doc` needs to be removed:

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/charts/logs/_doc/L04dU2gBnyB5Q6tBoTIw"
                                        ^    ^
                                        |    |
                                  remove one of those
```

In order to know which one to remove, retrieve your index mapping and use the one mapping type name that you can find there.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/charts 

{
  "charts" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {         <--- use the name you find here
      ...
```

Comment: Even running this command gives me the same error. Is it because I had deleted this index previously and started sending data again.    {"ok":false,"message":"Deleted cluster."}                                                                                    is it teling me the cluster is deleted? because if I try to create an index using the same name it says already exists and I see it on kibana too.

Comment: What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/health?v` + `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v` (update your question with the output)

Comment: yes. The problem was with the way I had sent the url.